# Laravel / Sentry won't save data on session or cookie after authenticate

Tags: php, session, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I just uploaded my code from localhost to a shared host, everything is fine in localhost but i cannot use user data on shared hosting after authenticating ... it's null.

Here is my Login code :

```
    try{$credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

        if(Sentry::authenticate($credentials, Input::get('remember'))){

            return Redirect::route('manager.index');

        }

    } catch ...
```

Then after redirecting to next page my output is null !!

```
public function index()
{

    $user = Sentry::getUser();
    dd($user);
    return View::make('manager.backend.index')->with('user', $user)->with('title', 'Dashboard');
}
```

My Session driver is DB and works fine in localhost.

Comment: You should check this setting app/config/app.php {{ 'url' => '', }} and app/config/session.php {{ 'domain' => null, }}

Comment: both of them are ok and the same. => "http://my.domain.com"

Comment: Well do you have a $user object in your login code  if(Sentry::authenticate($credentials, Input::get('remember'))){
            dd($user);
            return Redirect::route('manager.index');

        }

Comment: Yes i have output there it's logged in while i don't refresh the page